# LoadRunner Citrix protocol Regular expression function

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

What is the name of function in Citrix protocol of LoadRunner to capture the text with the help of regular expression? 
Please give a example.

Comment: Which text are you talking about? A text visible on the screen?

Comment: Yes text visible on screen, let me make it little more clear. When we use ctrx get text we have to give the coordinates of the text box, which may vary. But I’m looking for the regular expression function by which we can find exact solution of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way Citrix protocol works you currently have no way to "search" for text with regexp or otherwise. Your only options are the `ctx_get_text` steps, each using a different method to try and retrieve the text. If you think that something like regexp search is a useful feature please suggest it as an ER.